# How to solve ‘add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target:...’

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu: 12.04

ROS: Hydro

I learn to write .cfg file according to WiKi[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile)

After I finished it and ran `catkin_make`, error occurred.

```
 add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target: example_node
```

How can I solve it ?
Thank you ~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220575/how-to-solve-%E2%80%98add_dependencies-adding-dependency-to-non-existent-target:...%E2%80%99/) by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, do you have an example_node?

The line

```
add_dependencies(example_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

ensures, that the the target "example_node" is built after the target ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg. If you did not create this target before, you get your error.

In this context: If you don't have any node using your .cfg, then just delete this line. BUT what good is a .cfg file for, if you don't use it in a node?! So I assume that sooner or later you will create a node that will use your .cfg and then you need to make sure the .cfg is processed before the node is built.

Assuming you use c++ for your nodes:

```
add_executable(my_node src/my_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(my_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

Replace `my_node` by whatever your node is called and `src/my_node.cpp` by the according source file.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on 2015-11-08**:
Thanks a lot ! The procedure in ROS Wiki confused me. I should `catkin_make` first to generate the `xx.Config.h` file, then `add_dependencies(example_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)` to make my  `.cpp` file. Then it works. Thanks very much~